# Make "Answer similar questions" a link

Tags: feature-request, answer-similar-questions

I noticed the "Answer similar questions" feature. First thing I noticed is that it's an HTML button with a click event attached to it. This makes it impossible to open it in a new tab.

I would like to open it in a new tab, because I usually keep my answer open too, to see if there are any important comments, other answers or changes to the question that I might want to address. But while waiting for that, I could check out those 'similar' questions.

So my suggestion: make it a normal link. Style it as a button if you like, but make it work like a link.

Comment: One could also argue that if clicking results in the browser navigating away from the page then a <button> is semantically wrong in the first place.

Comment: Where is this feature at specifically?  I see an "answer similar questions" at the bottom of this page, but I am able to right click and open in a new tab...

Comment: It's shown as a popup above your answer after you answer a question. Maybe not all the time.

Comment: @ivarni, HTML buttons have caused navigation since the beginning of time.  Form submission occurs by requesting a new page, potentially using a HTTP POST operation instead of GET, depending on the FORM's METHOD attribute.  It's only more recently (in DHTML and especially since AJAX) that buttons that ran script locally instead of accessing a server URL (or accessing the server but not navigating) became possible.

Comment: @BenVoigt That is true, but we're not talking about submitting a form here. POSTing the answer is a form submission, going to another page with a list of related questions is not.

Comment: @BenVoigt: FWIW, that's why there are addons in e.g. Firefox that allow form submittal to a new background tab — the UX is fundamentally shaky to power users, even for something as comparatively well-accepted as forms.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: That's also supported in the pure HTML spec, via the WINDOW attribute... What's not supported directly is giving the user the choice of opening the resulting page in the current or another tab/window/viewer

Comment: Why not simply do vice-versa? i.e. open your current page in a new tab, and open similar question in current tab.

Comment: @LalitKumarB That's a viable workaround, but as for the "why not", because it's a clunky workaround which should not be necessary in the first place.

Answer (score 11):

I completely agree with this feature request.

I just noticed that the banner to find another answer is back. Really neat feature, but there is one issue that bothers me a little about it.

[image]

In order to get to similar questions, I have to click on a *button*. The issue here is that I don't want to navigate away straight after answering in case I need to polish my answer or respond to comments. What I want to do is open the "similar questions" in a new tab.

Please change the element from an input to an anchor to support this so that it is more usable. At present, the only way to use it is to duplicate the current tab and then click the link which is painful from a UX standpoint and makes the feature harder to access.

Comment: Naturally, I completely agree with you, but I have to say that your answer is actually just my question again. :o) I just noticed the feature again, while it seemed to have been gone for weeks. Maybe this is also the reason SO is so slow atm.

Comment: @GolezTrol - I wrote all of this up and realized it was a duplicate of your question so I wanted to show some support for your cause :) Posting here at least bumps your post to the top of the active list and still makes a case in favor of your request.