# Please keep the links Vimium compatible

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-experience

Stack Overflow is one of the sites with the best [Vimium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb?hl=en) compatibility that I have seen.

I used to surf it pretty well keyboard-only.

This is how it should be:

[image: All the links reachable via Vimium!]

Yet today I found one edge case:

On my profile site, I can track either my next privilege or next badge, and while I can click the icon, the two entries in the popup are not reachable via Vimium:

[image: Stack Overflow]

Please don't make me use the mouse and whenever you add links, just make sure they are `anchor` tags. Even if they perform some JavaScript magic. It helps a lot navigating the site so much easier!

Another case also appears on the signup form via other google etc.:

[image: Signup form showing failing of vimium]

Comment: I use Vimium too, but like Vim, I concede that there are points in my workflow where using a mouse is just more convenient than keystrokes.

Comment: [For shame](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2777280/229044) StackOverflow!

Comment: I would think general accessibility (people who have difficulty navigating with a mouse) concerns would more important to consider then a browser plugin. Though I agree it would be nice if fixing one fixes the other.

Comment: @JoeW True enough. One may open a new feature-request taking that approach more into account.

Comment: @meagar You've been sitting on that 6 years, haven't you? :)

Comment: @patricksweeney Wow, I guess I have. Time flies.

Comment: +1, you draw the red highlight using the keyboard!  -1, I still prefer [freehand circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138031/is-there-a-joke-about-freehand-circles-that-im-oblivious-to).

Comment: Should we call it a [[meta-tag:bug]], not a [feature-request]?

Comment: I've noticed the same thing with the "show <n> new questions," "this post has been edited, click to load," etc. banners (cVim/Pentadactyl, but doesn't matter). Never bothered to report it though.

Comment: +1 Also, when looking to answer the new questions, It would be nice if the `1 question with new activity` bar is also reacheable through vimium(Right now, it's not). I constantly need to reach the mouse to load new questions on the same page :(

Comment: Isn't this situation : having interactive ("clickable") elements semantically included in list form within other "clickable" elements--in this case, a `<ul>` with clickable `<li>` elements that is presented after clicking the `<a>` element (the little cog icon) -- the main motivation of the totally unimplemented `menu` element (now grasping for adoption in the HTML 5.1 draft)? https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/semantics.html#the-menu-element

Comment: Apparently StackOverflow has [a habit of making links that are not actually links](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287075/make-answer-similar-questions-a-link).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Done:

[image]

Please report any similar issues that you find in the future as well.

Comment: Did you take http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287075/make-answer-similar-questions-a-link into account?

Comment: @k0pernikus Nope, I'll take a look. Thanks!

Comment: I have added another example to the question body. Is that approach ok or do you want me to open new issues for each finding?

Comment: @k0pernikus I think it is better to open a new bug report, that makes easier for us to track it. Thanks!

Comment: Created new ticket at: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326661/keep-links-vimium-compatible-on-signup-form?lq=1

Answer (score 35):

As they are more buttons than links, adding `role="button"` ARIA-attribute would make more sense than making them anchors (if making them regular `<button>`-elements is not an option for whatever reasons :))

> The button role should be used for clickable elements that trigger a response when activated by the user. On its own, role="button" can make any element (e.g. `<p>`, `<span>` or `<div>`) appear as a button control to a screen reader. Additionally, this role can be used in combination with the aria-pressed attribute in order to create toggle buttons.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_button_role

This also fixes the issue with Vimium:

[image: Vimium hotlink]

(This obviously applies to other parts of SO that should/could be more accessible too)

Comment: do note this comment though there "Warning: Be careful when marking up links with the button role. Buttons are expected to be triggered using the Space key, while links are expected to be triggered through the Enter key. In other words, when links are used to behave like buttons, adding role="button" alone is not sufficient. It will also be necessary to add a key event handler that listens for the Space key in order to be consistent with native buttons."