# Keep links vimium compatible on signup form

Tags: bug, design, user-experience

I have found another instance of non-vimiunable link on the signup form:

[image: vimium link]

I want to be able to select google, facebook or email and password signup.

Comment: Parent bug ticket ^^ http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316022/please-keep-the-links-vimium-compatible/323483?noredirect=1#comment360141_323483