# "1 new answer to this question" is not Vimium-compatible

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-experience

> 1 new answer to this question

The "link" is a actually a `div` and is thus not screenreader-compatible (or in my case not [Vimium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vimium)-compatible). Vimium is an extension for Chrome which adds keyboard shortcuts for a lot of browser functionalities.

[image]

Comment: To whomever voted to close this question: vimium is an extension for Chrome which adds keyboard shortcuts for a lot of browser funcionalities. The OP wants to load new answers with a keyboard shortcut but the current HTML makes it difficult to do so (vimium or no vimium, actually).

Comment: @renan Your comment missed the "edit" link by a few pixels.

Comment: related earlier issues that were fixed: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316022/please-keep-the-links-vimium-compatible

Comment: I suppose technically it should be a `<button>`, would that work for your extension?

Comment: It applies to questions/answers with a new edit, as well.  I would imagine that a fix to one would fix them all, though.

Comment: You may want to post this on the main meta http://meta.stackexchange.com since its an issue with all sites.

Comment: @cat I certainly didn't say it was unwelcome here.

Comment: I'm not a "Vimium" user; can you please tell me - does "Vimium" support tabindex? meaning: if I add `tabindex="0"` to a regular `<div>`, it becomes "tabbable"; is that enough for "Vimium" to use it? maybe we just need to try it...

Comment: It's not about being tabbable, but about accessibility (for Vimium or any screen reader). A `<div>` does not carry a semantic meaning of being a clickable item. I'm pretty much aligned with this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2777280/632133

Comment: @Oleg accessibility is a valid concern; however, I am *not* going to assume that "any screen reader" follows the same semantics as Vimium. They are separate things. I'm can look at making it more semantically idiomatic, but the trick is always trying to do that without breaking things too much :)

Answer (score 6):

These pieces should have `<a>` anchors in the next build. I *think* I've managed to squeeze it in without them breaking completely, but please do let me know if they're now unusable :)

Comment: Current experience on unusability (not using vimium): 1. The bar is no longer clickable, need to click on the link text. 2. `F` shortcut key no longer working.

Comment: @laalto 1: yes, that's how idiomatically how links work; 2: will be fixed in a moment

Comment: Why not a `<button>`?

Comment: @Stijn we're pretty sparing with our use of button, and we usually only use it when you're *actually doing something* (as in: changing data); stylistically, it would be inconsistent to use a button here

Comment: I'm not sure if I correctly understand your second point, do you mean that you can't properly style the element (you can) or that it would be inconsistent compared to your 'normal' use of buttons? It would also solve the first problem of @laalto. Usability for screenreaders improved, but usability for non-screenreaders is less now. A button is also the most semantically correct element imho, but I suppose opinions on that can be different :)

Comment: @Stijn "less now" how? what is less? is the problem simply that you need to click on the text now?

Comment: Before this change, couldn't you click anywhere in the grey area? If not, then disregard my comments.

Comment: @Stijn *yes*, but ... I'm not sure that's *necessarily* a desirable feature - more an accident of how it was implemented. We can probably make it work again if this is somehow a blocker...

Comment: @MarcGravell It's OK, it's just a small detail. No need to spend too much time on it :)

Comment: @Stijn that said: we do have a "hand" icon on the entire div, so it probably should be restored to full clickability... sigh

Comment: I agree. If there's a "hand" icon on the entire div, the click function should be applied on the entire div.

Comment: @Murilo deploying fix now

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis that's the same thing we've been discussing for the last 10-ish comments; should be fixed **right now**