# Posts flickers if text is selected

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, web-sockets

For one or two days, I've noticed that questions on Stack Overflow are frequently flickering: disappearing for a short while and then reappearing.

I first thought it did it when a new edit or comment was posted (which would already be annoying), but it seems to do it sometimes even when nothing is changed in the question nor in the comments.

I'm using Firefox 48.0.1, on OSX, and haven't tested with other browsers (so maybe it's a Firefox-only glitch).

Has anyone experienced the same thing?

Comment: I have Firefox (actually Waterfox, but same source) on Windows and haven't seen this behavior either. Hard to imagine the type of "flicker" that you are describing. Do you mean that the page is repeatedly reloading without you asking it to?

Comment: I use Chrome on a Mac - no such problems. Perhaps Firefox auto-updated recently and that causes this glitch.

Comment: Some posts started blinking whenever I clicked on them, or when I clicked on the comments box to start writing. Chrome on Windows XP (yeah, I know...). I can't reproduce it anymore right now.

Comment: I started noticing it this morning too.  Safari 7.1.6 on Mac OSX (10.9.5). It's incredibly frustrating, as I can't vote-to-close or anything like that.

Comment: @Stijn what version of Firefox? (I'm failing to reproduce the issue)

Comment: @MarcGravell 48.0.1, but I can't reproduce it reliably.

Comment: This does happen to me.  Just stated a day or too ago.  I'm running Win 7 pro 64bit Chrome Version 52.0.2743.116 m.  I do have users scripts installed but nothing new.  I also have to refresh a time or two on a page in order to edit a a post otherwise it just blinks when I click the edit button.

Comment: I've seen this recently but I'm having a hard time tracking down the cause to reproduce it. The last time it happened to me I was clicking the close link and the question just refreshed every time I clicked it. The close dialog wouldn't come up and I didn't get the warning about only being able to open the close dialog every 3 seconds. I had to reload the page to make it stop.

Comment: It is actually *oscillating*. This is unfortunately [a recurring problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166483/153008) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I have a suspicion that [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333089/1-new-answer-to-this-question-is-not-vimium-compatible) might have caused the issue.

Comment: No repro, IE6/vista

Comment: It happens to me too. Google Chrome 52.0.2743.116 on Linux.

Comment: @MarcGravell this are the repro steps: Load any question page, for example: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332200. Let [someone else](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/32516315#32516315) do an edit on that post. Once the websocket message `action: "552-question-331817", data: "{"a":"post-edit","id":332200,"acctid":927180}"}` is received by you, the post will flicker when clicked. That continues until you reload the page.

Comment: @rene that is epic and much appreciated, thanks. Will absolutely look, but 3 day weekend here in the UK now

Comment: @MarcGravell don't worry, we will wait for you with some php code we want you to fix >:D

Comment: I *think* I've seen something sort of like this, on Chromium 51.0.2704.79-0ubuntu0.  (Ubuntu 15.10).  It never really caused a problem, and I assumed it was just this slow computer (Core2Duo 2.4GHz, Linux open-source drivers for Radeon HD4670 graphics).  I'll keep an eye out if it happens again.

Comment: Kudos for what looks like a relatively difficult repro case, @rene :)

Comment: This happens for me every single time a post is edited while I'm on the page

Comment: Happens for me too http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283925/230261

Comment: @Marc exact same thing happens to me in Safari 9.1.2 on OS X but without clicking I think, just flickering more often than there were edits on the post

Comment: Happens to me too, Chrome(Version 51.0.2704.103 m, 64-bit) on Windows 10 pro 64bit

Comment: Its happening to me also. I also notice that the `edit` menu fails to open the editor, and the `close` menu fails to open the close dialog in some cases as well (WIndows 7 + FF 48.0.2) Page refresh fixes both situations

Comment: @MarcGravell: This is really irritating and still happening, any word on when it will be addressed?

Comment: This prevents the "edit tags"  functionality because when clicking the link, the question flashes instead.

Comment: [I found the cause!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284194)

Comment: @MarcGravell ^^^

Comment: [It's fixed now.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283925/posts-disappear-briefly-then-reload-when-i-click-them#comment921517_284194)

Comment: @JasonC oh great; that means I caused it too... :(

Answer (score 24):

I've managed to reproduce this with Firefox 48.0.1 on Windows, but I'm not yet sure what causes it. Every time I click on [this question's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333237/annoying-add-regarding-job-in-so) text, it seems to destroy and recreate the `<td class="postcell">`, or at the very least set the `opacity` to `0` and animate it back to `1`.

Here are two screenshots with the attached event handlers on a parent element, may help the developers in debugging this:

[image: event 1]
[image: event 2]

Comment: Where do you click exactly in that question? In FF 46.0.1 on Win10 I have no repro.

Comment: @rene Anywhere in the question's text. I was trying to select a part of the text, but the bug makes it impossible. I can't reproduce it anymore on that question, so there must be a pre-condition or an event that activates the bug.

Comment: Is it maybe when there is an image in a question? Are you maybe on an very large screen?

Comment: @rene I briefly suspected it to only happen after reloading a question due to an edit, but I'm pretty sure I managed to reproduce it again without that happening. I'm on a regular 1920x1080 screen.

Comment: I just had this happen to me. The OP had just edited their question so the first flash, I assume, was just the question updating. But then anytime I tried to select some text it happened again.

Comment: Ok, I have it repro-ed as well. It happens indeed when an websocket message arrives to show the *question edited* notification. That message doesn't seem to be shown, instead the question flickers as described.

Comment: I just noticed it happens on answers, too. Not just on questions.

Comment: I've posted reproduction steps as a comment on the question.

Comment: Ilmari Karonen managed to find [the specific cause of the issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284194/230261).

Answer (score 12):

I see it in Chromium 51.0.2704.79-0ubuntu0 (on x86-64 Ubuntu 15.10 with open-source ATI graphics (HD4670)) when casting an upvote on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39178985/how-portyield-works-in-freertos/39181166#39181166), or even clicking anywhere on the post.

The whole text of the answer momentarily disappears, so I just see the background colour.

Clicking outside the post doesn't cause the effect.

---

**This was within the first 5 mins of the answer being posted.  After refreshing the page (after the 5min edit window, but I didn't try earlier), I no longer see the flickering.**