# Pressing close blinks the question

Tags: bug, vote-to-close

When I try to open the close dialog on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293560), it just blinks the question and logs the following error in the console:

> ```
> VM144:43 Uncaught TypeError: scope.querySelector is not a function
> engage @ VM144:43
> (anonymous function) @ VM144:119
> dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
> i @ jquery.min.js:3
> trigger @ jquery.min.js:3
> trigger @ jquery.min.js:3
> w @ jquery.min.js:4
> d @ jquery.min.js:4
> ```

[image]

Comment: Works for me, but I bet the problem is similar to: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333225/3933332