# Question editor auto closes when another edit is submitted while editing

Tags: bug, edits, notifications, editor

Over the last several days I was bitten enough times to be sure that the following is actually happening, is not a coincidence, and started happening only recently:

- I start editing a question.
- While doing it I receive a notification that another edit was submitted.
- I'm going to save what I've done so far by selecting it all and copying to the clipboard - the chances are, the new edit is a crappy one that fixes one issue out of ten.
- But when I click the question editor, the editor closes, my edit is lost before I could copy it, and the new edit appears on the page. To add insult to injury, the new edit is indeed a crappy one.

This is extremely annoying.

Additional information:

- After that happens, each click on the question body causes the fadeout-fadein animation on the entire question that is used to bring in new content. This stops when I reload the page.
- After that happens, when I try to reload the page, I still get the prompt whether I actually want to leave the page given that I'm editing the question even though the editor has closed itself.

I'm using Firefox 47.0.1 on Windows 7 SP1.

<s>Edit: I believe the reason is that the click even bubbles up to the notification bar that handles it not realizing it bubbled up.</s>

Comment: Possibly related: [Posts flickers if text is selected](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333225/3853934).

Comment: @Gothdo this is somehow relevant https://twitter.com/irqed/status/358212928404586498?

Comment: This change in behaviour is annoying.  You used to be able to take a copy of what you've done on the edit, then refresh and work out whether what you had before was safe to use in the revised version (it often was).  Now you do not get that option — SO unilaterally throws away possibly significant effort on its behalf and wastes my time and decreases the energy that I'm willing to put into improving content.

Comment: I experienced the same behavior in Chrome.

Comment: I've had the same problem in FF48.02 on Win10x64. Workaround: [Textarea Cache Firefox add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/textarea-cache/): "This extension will save automatically the content in textarea or WYSIWYG editor when user is typing. User can recover the saved texts in the cache window, even the tab or the window is closed unexpectedly."  I have no association with this add-on except as a happy user. I've been using it for years. It works well to recover text area input, even auto-saves multiple versions of the same page in addition to a drop down list by page&time.

Comment: I hope this is remedied soon. I just lost a massive formatting edit because someone removed a tag.... FUUUUUUUUUUUUUU......

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Same happened to me just yesterday, TWICE in a row!

Comment: Can we have a response on this please. It's ridiculous. Yet again I just lost a sizable grammar and formatting edit simply because someone added a [god damn apostrophe to the title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39624396/php-function-wont-execute-on-ajax-post#39624396). This UX is appallingly bad and is both actively preventing me from improving question content and from wanting to even bother to continue in the future.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan A workaround is to not click anything when that happens. Keyboard only, Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C.

Comment: The problem there is there's no warning that it's going to happen - the editor just disappears. There's no time to copy the changes you've made.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No, a notification bar always appears above the editor. When that happens, do not use the mouse.

Comment: That was the old behaviour which seems to have changed. Perhaps they're A/B testing it now, but I can guarantee you I'm not getting that bar.

Comment: It would appear this stopped in `rev 2016.10.8.4048` - well, fits into 6 to 8 weeks!

Comment: On a second thought, this may only be fixed when the editor displays; it would appear the question still reloads when clicking anywhere in the question body when the notification appears but you did not try to edit the question.