# Small and minor bug when loading question changes while editing it

Tags: bug, edits

**Scenario**: I'm editing a question, while someone else just submit a change before I finished my edit. I reload the changes, and next I try to navigate away to another page.

**Steps to reproduce**:

1. Edit any question, add an extra space even, but DON'T save the edit.
2. Open the question in a new tab, edit it, and save.
3. On the tab from step 1, you should now see a notification *"an edit has been made to this post; click to load"* Click on it and load the changes.
4. Now click on the History back/forward button, or on a link that will make you navigate away from the page.

**Expected result**: Since I reload the changes in the post, and I'm not editing anything, I should just be redirected.

**Actual result**: I get a confirm box with the text "Changes you made may not be saved" See attached screenshot:

[image]

As you can see - Although I'm not in editing mode, the confirm still pops.

Tested on Chrome v. 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)

Comment: I think your STR have a problem; I've never seen an edit notification come up for my own edits to the same post, [except when improving someone else's edit suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272314/suggested-edit-queue-shows-conflict-warning-for-my-own-edit-after-submitting-imp).

Comment: @NathanTuggy I'm not sure about that, what I do know it that the notification shows when you edit someone else's post, as you said. But I don't think anybody noticed my bug report at all do it doesn't matter

Comment: This is a leftover of somewhat fixed http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333831/11683.

Comment: @GSerg If your bug report is fixed then it would also fix mine. But I don't see yours under a `[status-completed]` tag

Comment: @AlonEitan It's somewhat fixed as I said. It stopped destroying the edits, but without ever being officially recognized, and the minor annoyances remain.